# Any suggestion on MySQL services?

Tags: mysql

I would like to separate my production server into 2, one for running code, the other one is for DB, which is MySQL.

Is there any suggestion if I would like to subscribe a MySQL service? I have few applications need such standalone database service. So I would like to a service which allow me to create as many database as I want.

Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: Questions about recommending hosting providers really aren't a good fit here.

Comment: thanks mate. so where should i ask for recommendation?

Comment: Pro Webmasters generally has hosting suggestions (webmasters.stackexchange.com) but is there anything really stopping you from getting another server with your present host and running MySQL on it? (it makes a *lot* more sense to keep your database server in the same datacenter as the application servers which depend upon it)

Comment: thanks @danlefree. will take a look on Pro Webmasters. I would like to get a "cloud database" which someone experienced will handle all the security and performance issue for me. It takes time to building it myself as I am not so professional on these aspect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/), it fits your request of a "cloud database" but the prices can be a bit steep.

Answer (score 0):

Why not run a standalone system for MySQL, like a [VPS](http://www.linode.com/?r=c76fb744149d3f658d38406bb2606bb783bf3d23). I used to run my dev and production servers on a couple of these, with replicated MySQL DBs on separate nodes.